# NullReferenceException in If Statement

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Ok so when I run this i run into a null exception in the if statement on workshops[2]. The messagebox shows the value that i expected. Thoughts?

```
foreach (string[] workshops in data.aWorkJag)
{
    MessageBox.Show(workshops[2].ToString());
    if (workshops[1].ToString() == wkshpConfCode)
    {
        toAddList.Add(workshops[2].ToString());
    }
}
```

The exception is being thrown on the line

> toAddList.Add(workshops[2].ToString());

Comment: You are displaying third item [2], but accessing second item [1], which I think is null

Comment: toAddList.Add(workshops[2].ToString()); is what throws the null exception sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `workshops[2]` has a value but `workshops[1]` is null. The `ToString()` method throws an exception if you call it on a `null` value.

Assuming that's not just a typo, you can use `Convert.ToString()`, which does a null check and returns an empty string:

```
if (Convert.ToString(workshops[1]) == wkshpConfCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that toAddList is initialized

Comment: Did something silly and had the variable set to null. Would seem rather obvious but I do that allot. Thank you.